# Property of integer polynomials which are divisible by $k$.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Suppose $f \in Z[x]$ is such that every term is divisible by an integer $k$, but $k$ does not divide all of its coefficients and it is coprime with their union.
For example, $x^6 + 2x^2 + 3x$ is always divisible by 6.

I am trying to prove the following with no success so far (or produce a counterexample, but computer checking has so far found none):

**If for some even (or perhaps composite?) $n$ and all distinct pairs $i,j$ with $0 \leq i, j < n$ we have  $$\frac{f(i) - f(j)}{k}\not \equiv 0 \mod n,$$ then $\gcd(k,n)$ is a power of 2.**

Note that it is trivially true for linear $f$, for which $k$ could only be 
$1$, and also for quadratic $f$, for which $k$ could only be $1$ or $2$.  But once we get to cubics there is something to prove!
Also note that it is crucial that $n$ be composite, since counterexamples abound for $n$ prime.  I am not sure, however, if it is important whether we assume $n$ is even or just that $n$ is composite.

Any suggestions for things to try or proof ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Should read **If for some fixed pair $n,k,$** because your $k$ stays the same when $x,y$ vary. Meanwhile, the quick way to get polynomials is the binomial coefficient $(x, c) \cdot c!.$ This is just $x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-c+1),$ but is always divisible by $c!$ when $x$ is an integer.

Comment: i don't see your point about phrasing as a fixed pair...  $f(x)/k$ is a rational polynomial taking integer values.  The conjecture is that if the polynomial takes n consecutive distinct values modulo $n$, then $gcd(k,n)$ must be a power of $2$.  As for the polynomials from binomial coefficients, thanks for the suggestion.  That had also occurred to me and i used them as an early sanity check for many hundreds of n before asking, I believe those support the conjecture (though i did not prove).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. $f(x) = x(x-1)(x-2) + 3x$, $k=n=3$. $f(j)/3 = j$ for $j = 0, 1, 2$ so your condition is satisfied, but $\gcd(3,3)$ is not a power of $2$.

Comment: Thank you, but shoot i just realized i've only been looking at even n because in the greater context of what i'm working on odd n are not possible candidates. 

Can you produce another counter example with n being even?

Comment: And just to add, we can fashion a counterexample for any $n$ prime.

Comment: Set $f(x) = \frac{x \cdot (x+1) \cdots (x+p)}{p}$, and then the first $p$ terms are distinct mod $p$ for $p$ prime.

Comment: The same example works for any $N$. For example for $N=6$: take $n=k=6$ and $f(x)=x(x-1)\cdots(x-5) + 6x.$ Now $f(j)/6 = j$ for $j = 0, 1, \dots 5$.

Comment: ok, yep, that checks out!